# When can you not do a mapping composition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have $\alpha:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ and $\beta:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$. Looking over my notes, it says $\alpha \circ \beta$ can not be done but $\beta \circ \alpha$ can. What is the general rule here? I think it has to be something about the range being a subset of the domain but I'm not too clear on the specifics. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The range of $g$ must be a subset of the domain of $f$.

Is the necessary and sufficient condition for $f\circ g$ to exist.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't see this but how is R^+ not a subset of R^3?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is the set of triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that $x\in\mathbb{R},\,y\in\mathbb{R},\,z\in\mathbb{R}$. $$$$
$\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of positive real numbers.
$$$$
It is a fact concerning the set-theoretic formalization of mathematics that no real number is a triplet of real numbers.$$$$